# How can I return matched values in the order they are found?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have string values, read from file, that look like:

```
"a":
"group-one":
"b":
"c":
"string-value":"g1_value_1"
"c":
"string-value":"g1_value_2"
"group-two":
"d":
"e":
"string-value":"g2_val_1"
"e":
"string-value":"g2_val_2"
```

I need to search the string, return the matched values in the order they appear in the string. So the results need to look like:

```
"group-one":
"string-value":"g1_value_1"
"string-value":"g1_value_2"
"group-two":
"string-value":"g2_val_1"
"string-value":"g2_target_val_2"
```

I can easily search the string and return matching lines using:

```
extract_list = ["group-one", "group-two","string-value"]
for word in extract_list:
    for line in string.split('\n'):
        if word in line:
            print(line)
```

But how can I keep them in the correct order as noted in the example above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looping over the words first, then the lines, switch the order like so:

```
for line in string.splitlines():
    if any(word in line for word in extract_list):
        print(line)
```

This will preserve the order and will also go through the lines only once, instead of N times.